# AWS EC2 tags boto3: loop FOR with 2 tags and IF sorting tags

Tags: python, boto3

I have a code that looks through all ec2 instances and reads their tags and values. If there is some specific tag, there should be some action. If it is not present - another action. The problem appears when there are 2 tags - my code executes both 2 actions.

```
response = client_ec2.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
    { "Name": "instance-state-name", "Values": ["running"] },])

session = boto3.Session(region_name="us-west-2")
region = "us-west-2"

for reservation in response["Reservations"]:
    for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
        CPUUtilization = client_cw.get_metric_statistics(
            Namespace='AWS/EC2',
            MetricName='CPUUtilization',
            Dimensions=[{'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': instance["InstanceId"]}],
            StartTime=past,
            EndTime=now,
            Period=600,
            Statistics=['Average']
        )
        datapoints = CPUUtilization['Datapoints']
        last_datapoint = sorted(datapoints, key=itemgetter('Timestamp'))[-1]
        utilization = last_datapoint['Average']
        load = round(utilization, 1)
        timestamp = str(last_datapoint['Timestamp'])
        
        if load < 10:
            InstanceID = instance["InstanceId"]

            for tag in instance["Tags"]:
                if "TurnOff" in tag['Key'] and "False" in tag['Value']:
                    print("TurnOff False tag found. This instance will NOT be stopped")
                    print("CPU Utilization more than 0% on {0}\n".format(InstanceID))
                    break

                else:
                   print("TurnOff False tag not found. This instance WILL be stopped")
                   print("CPU Utilization more than 0% on {0}\n".format(InstanceID))
                   
                   continue
```

The result of script:

```
TurnOff False tag not found. This instance WILL be stopped
CPU Utilization more than 0% on i-1

TurnOff False tag found. This instance will NOT be stopped
CPU Utilization more than 0% on i-1

TurnOff False tag found. This instance will NOT be stopped
CPU Utilization more than 0% on i-2
```

It happens when instance i-1 has 2 tags:

```
env = prod
TurnOff = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I would switch away from the loop as you have it and instead make `tags` a dictionary where you exclusively search for `TurnOff`:

```py
tags = {tag['Key']: tag['Value'] for tag in instance["Tags"]}

if tags.get('TurnOff', False):
    # shutdown
else:
    # don't shutdown
```